# Replace nbsp; and HTML tags with empty space

Tags: javascript, html

I want to get rid of HTML tags and nbsp;
How can I combine these operations?

JS

```
 .replace(/&nbsp;/g,'').replace(/(<([^>]+)>)/ig,"")
```

Comment: `Java`!=`JavaScript`. If you are not sure which tag to use read its description.

Comment: I think it*'s the same for both

Comment: This problem would apply to all languages ​​that make replacements from regexp. This doesn't mean that there is a relationship between those languages ​​and syntaxes that do not differ ...

Answer (score 6):

Just join them together

```
.replace(/(&nbsp;|(<([^>]+)>))/ig,'');
```